# Any suggestion with my signalr codes?It is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, angularjs, signalr

I'm encountering now a serious problem about my signalr application.

What do you think that is lack to my code or any suggestion about signalr. I am new to signalr so can't really tell if it is correct.

I hope any suggestion or comment about my codes. Please anyone can review it.

All I want is when the database is changed my application will automatically change without refreshing the browser.

I also followed this limitation about `Broker` in SQL server
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181122.aspx

I also enable my database broker.

**Hub**

```
[HubName("iTestHub")]
    public class iTestHub : Hub
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
            Clients.All.hello();
        }
        public static void Show()
        {
            IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<iTestHub>();
            context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
        }
    }
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
var iTest = $.connection.iTestHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        iTest.client.displayStatus = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();

        function getData() {
            StudentExamService.GetStudentExam(studId + '|' + yearCode).then(function(results) {
                $scope.studentExams = results.data;
            });
        }
```

**Web API starup**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureApp(app);
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.MapSignalR();
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

**Globa.asax**

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CentralizedStudentInformationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency.Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Aptus-TestConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }

protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CentralizedStudentInformationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDependency.Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Aptus-TestConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke `getData()` function, after `start()` method is done:

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function(){
   getData();
});
```

Now, you will invoke get data after connection is established.